# What's the correct way for importing the whole module as well as a couple of its functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I know that `from module import *` will import all the functions in current namespace but it is a bad practice. I want to use two functions directly and use `module.function` when I have to use any other function from the module. What I am doing currently is:

```
import module
from module import func1, func2
# DO REST OF MY STUFF
```

Is it a good practice? Does the order of first two statements matter? 
Is there a better way using which I can use these two functions directly and use rest of the functions as usual with the module's name prepended to them?

Using just `import module` results in very long statements with a lot of repetition if I use the same function from the given module five times in a single statement. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: That's how most programmers do.

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter. Generally, you want to pick one or the other style (so use `module.func1` and `module.func2` everywhere too), but this is a *style choice*. I find it to be more consistent.

Comment: Calling same function five time itself looks weird to me. Check edit in my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not good to do (may be opinion based):

```
import module

from module import func1, func2  # `func1` and `func2` are already part of module
```

Because you already hold a reference to `module`.

If I were you, I would import it in the form of `import module`. Since your issue is that `module.func1()` becomes too long. I may import  the module and use `as` for creating a alias for the name. For example:

```
import module as mo
#                 ^ for illustration purpose. Even the name of 
#                   your actual module wont be `module`. 
#                   Alias should also be self-explanatory 

# For example:
import database_manager as db_manager
```

Now I may access the functions as:

```
mo.func1()
mo.func2()
```

---

**Edit**: Based on the edit in actual question

*If your are calling same function in the same line, there is possibility that your are already doing some thing wrong.* It will be great if you can share what your that function does.

For example: *Want to the rertun value of those functions to be passed as argument to another function?* as:

```
test_func(mo.func1(x), mo.func1(y). mo.func1(z))
```

could be done as:

```
params_list = [x, y, z]
func_list = [mo.func1(param) for param in params_list]
test_func(*func_list)
```

Comment: *Why* is in not good to do? It's just a style choice, after all, but you don't motivate why you should your alternative.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes. May be opinion based. Mentioned it in the answer as well along with *"If I were you, I would do"*. As per me it is not a good styling technique

Answer (score 1):

The order doesn't matter and it's not a pythonic way. When you import the `module` there is no need to import some of its functions separately again. If you are not sure how many of the functions you might need to use just import the module and access to the functions on demand with a simple reference.

```
# The only import you need 
import module

# Use module.funcX when you need any of its functions
```

After all, if you want to use some of your functions (much) more than the others, as the cost of attribute access is greater than importing the functions separately, you better to import them as you've done.

And still, the order doesn't matter. You can do:

```
import module
from module import func1, func2
```

For more info read the documentation https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not and I think this is the best (at least better)  way to go.

Comment: *I want to use two functions directly and use module.function when I have to use any other function from the module.*

Comment: I tried this approach but when I need to use the same function from the given module five times in a single statement, it becomes too long and repetitive.

That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @NeenaVivek You'd have mentioned this in your question. In  this case I think it's better to do what you've done cause at least it will reduce the number of attribute accesses.